# How to deploy apache server in openshift?

Tags: docker, deployment, openshift, web-deployment

I want to deploy the apache server on openshift. My server is running well on my local, but when I deploy it on openshift , I encounter the following issue

(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

The possible reason might be that apache runs as a root user, and openshift doesn't allows so!

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Port 80 is a reserved port and the default OpenShift [Security Context Constraints](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/additional_concepts/authorization.html#security-context-constraints) do not allow containers to run on this port.

You should use a container image that runs on a port like 8080 or 8443.

Comment: Hi ! I have the apache server running on my docker . But when I deploy it on openshift , it gives me the error "Action '-D FOREGROUND' failed". What could be the possible way to start the apache server. The simple start command does not works, as Apache is detached from the shell

Comment: The following Stack Overflow post seems to address this issue: [Action '-D FOREGROUND' failed. while building apache2 image with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266554/action-d-foreground-failed-while-building-apache2-image-with-docker)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration, refer [Enable Container Images that Require Root](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#enable-dockerhub-images-that-require-root)
 for more details.

If you run your httpd pod as `default` `serviceaccount`, you can grant `anyuid` scc for running as `root` user. You should restart your pod for taking effect your changes.

```
# oc get pod <your pod name> -o yaml | grep -i serviceAccountName
    serviceAccountName: default

# oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default

# oc delete pod <your pod name>
```

*UPDATE*: Basically the 80 port will not duplicated with host 80 port unless running with `hostnetwork` scc.
        Because container is isolated with host network using namespaces feature of kernel.

My testing evidence is as follows.

```
--- haproxy is already running with 80 port on the host.
# ss -ntlpo  | grep -w :80
LISTEN     0      128          *:80                       *:*                   users:(("haproxy",pid=22603,fd=6))

--- Create a project for testing
# oc new-project httpd-test

--- Create a httpd pod
# oc new-app --name httpd24 --docker-image=docker.io/httpd

--- Check the state of the pod
# oc get pod
NAME              READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
httpd24-1-hhp6g   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   8          19m

# oc logs httpd24-1-hhp6g
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.128.1.201. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

--- Configure "anyuid" for running the httpd pod with 80 port
# oc get pod httpd24-1-hhp6g -o yaml | grep -wi serviceaccountname
  serviceAccountName: default

# oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
scc "anyuid" added to: ["system:serviceaccount:httpd-test:default"]

# oc delete pod httpd24-1-hhp6g 
pod "httpd24-1-hhp6g" deleted

--- Check the state of httpd pod again
# oc get pod
NAME              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
httpd24-1-9djkv   1/1       Running   0          1m

# oc logs httpd24-1-9djkv 
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.128.1.202. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.128.1.202. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon May 06 12:10:47.487909 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 139699524075584] AH00489: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 06 12:10:47.488232 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 139699524075584] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: This will work in general, but fails in case of Openshift Router (HAProxy) already binding to it on the node. High ports 8080/8443 is safer - see Openshift Apache Image in the catalogue.

Comment: Hi ! I have the apache server running on my docker . But when I deploy it on openshift , it gives me the error "Action '-D FOREGROUND' failed". What could be the possible way to start the apache server. The simple start command does not works, as Apache is detached from the shell

Comment: @Milde Thank you for your point, I also agree your suggestion not using 80 port. But basically I think a container does not affect the port usage each other with running host. Look above my `UPDATE` section.

Comment: @Daein Park: yes, HAProxy (default OCP router) uses the Node IP (hostnetwork) for routing the traffic, so it does affect and will crash/block.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use the existing images for the Apache Server that are based on rhel7

`registry.redhat.io/rhscl/httpd-24-rhel7`

These images support S2I, exposes port 8080 and can run with any UID (not root). You can use the following template: [HTTPD template](https://github.com/openshift/library/blob/d7813f42982c83e0efd6b3782e42dcbc0580b8f6/arch/ppc64le/official/httpd/templates/httpd-example.json)

EDIT: I have updated the link to the right template.

Comment: Hi Ruben ! I have the apache server running on my docker . But when I deploy it on openshift , it gives me the error "Action '-D FOREGROUND' failed". What could be the possible way to start the apache server. The simple start command does not works, as Apache is detached from the shell.

Comment: You don't need to start it detached, why would you?

Comment: I don't want it to start detached. I just want to run it on openshift . Although openshift gives an error with the FOREGROUND command.

Comment: It seems you don't need a blank space between `-DFOREGROUND`

Comment: The link you provided is invalid.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa it is not a http link it is the image reference to the container registry. `$ podman pull registry.redhat.io/rhscl/httpd-24-rhel7`
You must first authenticate to the registry

Comment: On this end I see a link to a  json template that is invalid.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I have updated the link to the template